# Dart JavaScript output fails with: method not found: 'new ToDos:1:0' Receiver: Instance of 'JsClassMirror'

Tags: compilation, dart, dart-mirrors, dart2js

I've ported a handy JS library to Dart: [dartscale](https://github.com/martyglaubitz/dartscale). The crucial part of it's functionality can be broken down to:

```dart
final Map<Symbol, ClassMirror> _registeredModules = new Map<Symbol, ClassMirror>();

register(module, [String moduleName]) {
   final uniqueModuleName = moduleName != null ? moduleName : module.runtimeType.toString();
   final Symbol uniqueModuleIdentifier = new Symbol(uniqueModuleName);

   if (_registeredModules.containsKey(uniqueModuleName)) {
     throw new StateError("Module ${moduleName} already registered!");
   }

   final ClassMirror mirror = reflect(module).type;
  _registeredModules[uniqueModuleIdentifier] = mirror;
}

start(Symbol moduleName, String id, options) {
   if (!_registeredModules.containsKey(moduleName)) {
      throw new StateError("Module ${moduleName} not registered!");
   }

   final ClassMirror mirror = _registeredModules[moduleName];
   final Symbol moduleId = id != null ? new Symbol(id) : moduleName;
   final Sandbox sandbox = new Sandbox(this.mediator);

   if (_runningModules.containsKey(moduleId)) {
      throw new StateError("Module with id #${moduleId} already running!");
   }

   final InstanceMirror moduleInstance = mirror.newInstance(new Symbol(''), [sandbox], null);
   moduleInstance.invoke(new Symbol("start"), [options]);

   _runningModules[moduleId] = moduleInstance;
}
```

i also provide an example

```dart
part of example;

class ToDos {

    Sandbox _sandbox;

    DivElement _contentEl;
    int _nextToDoId = 0;

    UListElement _todoList;

     ToDos ([Sandbox this._sandbox]);

     start([Map options]) {
         this._initLocalStorage();

         var html = ['<div id="module-todos">',
                       '<form>',
                          '<input type="text" class="input-medium">',
                          '<button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>',
                       '</form>',
                       '<ul>',
                       '</ul>',
                     '</div>'].join('');

         this._contentEl = new Element.html(html);
         this._todoList = this._contentEl.query('ul');

         options['containerEl'].append(this._contentEl);

         window.localStorage.keys.forEach((key) => this._renderToDo(key));

         this._setupEvents();

         this._sandbox.channel('navigationbar').topic('filter').listen((filterContent) {
             this._filter(filterContent);
         });

        this._sandbox.channel('navigationbar').topic('clearfilter').listen((filterContent) {
           this._todoList.queryAll('li span').forEach((element) => element.parent.classes.remove('hide'));
        });
    }

    stop() {
        this._contentEl.remove();
    }

    _initLocalStorage() {
        if (window.localStorage.keys.length == 0) {
            var map = {
                "1": {
                    "subject": "Groceries: Banas and Apples",
                    "isDone": false
                },
                "2": {
                    "subject": "Taxes: take care of them",
                    "isDone": false
                },
                "3": {
                    "subject": "Bring out trash",
                    "isDone": false
                }  
            };

            for (var key in map.keys) {
                window.localStorage[key] = stringify(map[key]);
                this._nextToDoId++;
            }
        }
        else {
           for (var key in window.localStorage.keys) {
              var intKey = int.parse(key);

              if (intKey > this._nextToDoId) {
                  this._nextToDoId = intKey;
              }

              this._nextToDoId++;
           }
       }
   }

   _setupEvents() {
       var input = this._contentEl.query('input');

       input.onKeyDown.listen((event) {
          if (event.keyCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
              event.preventDefault();

              this._addToDo(input.value);
              input.value = '';
          }
       });

       this._contentEl.query('button[type="Submit"]').onClick.listen((event) {
           event.preventDefault();

           if (input.value.length > 0) {
               this._addToDo(input.value);
               input.value = '';
           }
       });

       this._todoList.onClick.listen((MouseEvent event) {
           var el = event.target;

           if (el.classes.contains('icon-remove')) {
               this._deleteToDo(el.parent);
           }
           else if (el.classes.contains('icon-ok')) {
               this._toggleToDoDone(el.parent);
           }
       });
   }

   _renderToDo(id) {
       var todoObject = parse(window.localStorage[id.toString()]);

       var html = ['<li class="record-todo ', todoObject["isDone"]?"done":"",'" data-id="', id,'">',
                      '<span>', todoObject["subject"], '</span>',
                      '<i class="icon icon-ok"></i>',
                      '<i class="icon icon-remove"></i>',
                  '</li>'].join('');

       this._todoList.append(new Element.html(html));
   }

   _addToDo(text) {
       var todoJson = stringify({
           "subject": text,
           "isDone": false
       });

       window.localStorage[this._nextToDoId.toString()] = todoJson;
       this._renderToDo(this._nextToDoId);

       this._nextToDoId++;
   }

   _deleteToDo(todoLIElement) {
       window.localStorage.remove(todoLIElement.dataset["id"]);

       todoLIElement.remove();
   }

   _toggleToDoDone(todoLIElement) {
       var done = !todoLIElement.classes.contains('done'); 
       var id = todoLIElement.dataset["id"];
       var todoObject = parse(window.localStorage[id]);
       todoObject["isDone"] = done;
       window.localStorage[id] = stringify(todoObject);

       if (done) {
          todoLIElement.classes.add('done');
       }
       else {
          todoLIElement.classes.remove('done');
       }
   }

   _filter(content) {
       this._todoList.queryAll('li span').forEach((element) {
            if (element.innerHtml.contains(content)) {
                element.parent.classes.remove('hide');
            }
            else {
               element.parent.classes.add('hide');
            }
       });
   }
}
```

in my App.dart

```dart
library example;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json';
import '../lib/dartscale.dart';

part 'dart/ToDos.dart';

main () {
    var core = new Core();
    core.register(new ToDos());

    core.start("ToDos", "ToDos", {
        "containerEl": query('body > .container')
    });
}
```

bug in dart2js ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Where's the bug? What's the problem that's happening?

Comment: i point it out in the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Turns out that dart2js has problems with mirrored calls on Methods/Constructors which have optional positional Arguments.
So changing

```dart
class ToDos {
   Sandbox _sandbox;
   ToDos([Sandbox this._sandbox]);
}
```

to

```dart
class ToDos {
   Sandbox _sandbox;
   ToDos(Sandbox this._sandbox); //make the argument non-optional
}
```

solved my Problem

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, since you don't state what's going wrong, but some general advice. Mostly, I'd avoid `new Symbol()` and mirrors if you can easily avoid them, and in this case you can.

First, you should figure out if you want to register module instances or produce instances on demand, you probably don't want both like you are here. If you register an instance, then can't you just reuse that instance? Does `start()` need to produce new instances as part of its spec? You turn around and try to make sure that an instance isn't already running anyway.

If you really do need to produce instances, a simple factory function will eliminate the need for mirrors. So instead of:

```dart
core.register(new ToDos());
```

You write:

```dart
core.register('ToDos', () => new ToDos());
```

If you still want to use mirrors, you can clean up the use of `new Symbol()`. Here's some recommendations:

- Don't use Symbols as keys unless you're really getting them from reflective APIs like mirrors and noSuchMethod in the first place. Just use the String name or maybe the runtimeType. In your case you're mixing Symbols and Strings as keys in your `_registeredModules` map, which is probably causing some bugs, like modules will never appear to be registered. (are you testing in checked mode?)
- Don't use `new Symbol('name')`, use `const Symbol('name')`
- Don't use InstanceMirror.invoke, getField, or setField when you can just call the method directly. In your code you can replace

  ```
  moduleInstance.invoke(new Symbol("start"), [options]);
  ```

  with

  ```
  moduleInstance.reflectee.start(options);
  ```
- Factories aren't evil. It'd be nice to invoke a constructor from a type instance, but until then registering a factory is pretty lightweight in Dart.

Here's your code with those suggestions:

```dart
typedef Object Factory(Sandbox sandbox);

final Map<Symbol, Factory> _registeredModules = new Map<Type, Factory>();

register(Type type, Factory factory) {
   if (_registeredModules.containsKey(type)) {
     throw new StateError("Module $type already registered!");
   }
   _registeredModules[type] = factory;
}

start(Type type, options) {
   if (!_registeredModules.containsKey(type)) {
      throw new StateError("Module $type not registered!");
   }
   if (_runningModules.containsKey(type)) {
      throw new StateError("Module $type already running!");
   }
   Sandbox sandbox = new Sandbox(this.mediator);    
   var module = _runningModules[type](sandbox)..start(options);
   _runningModules[type] = module;
}
```

Comment: 1: "() => new ToDos()" - never thought about that approach, but i want to do it via Mirroring and the concept has proofen since everything is fine in the Dart VM. 

2:"since you don't state what's going wrong": look a the subject of the question: im getting a exception (in Dart style cause of source maps) when trying to run the webapp under dart2js output in a normal browser

Comment: Mirrors currently have a big cost in dart2js. I wouldn't use them unless really necessary.

Comment: i absolutly know that they're costly, but nevertheless: if it works in Dart, than i expect it to work after compilation to JS. that's the promise they make...

Comment: There absolutely isn't the promise that mirrors won't have a negative impact on performance or compiled JS size. Using mirrors in dart2js produces warnings for a reason.

Comment: "i absolutly know that they're costly.." dude, i know that... my oint is: "if it works in Dart, than i expect it to work after compilation to JS"

Comment: Saying that you expect it to work well in JS when the Dart team says that mirrors in JS are costly in both performance and code size is contradictory. I just want to make sure you know that mirrors might never work as well in JS as they do natively in all cases, and even when they don't have a major code size impact, it might require that you annotate your code significantly to give hints to the compiler.

Comment: having things to just work and have it work perfomant are two completly seperate things. i was just talking about the first thing

Comment: OK, gotcha. You issue is definitely a bug in dart:mirrors. I still want people to be careful about using mirrors though. Someone using your library naively could easily see their app blow up to many MB. If there's an easy non-mirror alternative, I'd always choose that.

Comment: yes, i just got bitten by this: the outputted JS code of my example app is about 3 MB <_<